# Как сделать пропуск пробелов?

Tags: c#, sql

Здравствуй весь ХэшКод, у меня есть такой код

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerSpawn--;
        labelTimer.Text = "Таймер: " + timerSpawn;
        if (timerSpawn == 0)
        {
            timerSpawn = 10;
            MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            try
            {
                cnt.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = cnt.CreateCommand();
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = cnt.CreateCommand();
                MySqlCommand cmd3 = cnt.CreateCommand();

                cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + timer;

                MySqlDataReader readURK = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                if (readURK.Read())
                {
                    labelUrl.Text = "URL: " + readURK["URL"].ToString();
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(readURK["URL"].ToString());

                    readURK.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    statusNow.Text = "Нету работы";
                    statusNow.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                timer++;
            }
            finally
            {
                cnt.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Так вот у меня в базе есть запись с ID 77 и запись с ID 79, 80, 81 и т.д. **но** код, он идет с начала на ID 77 и всё... после следующего срабатывания таймера, таймер останавливается т.к. дальше **нету** id 78, так вот как пропустить все пробелы, оставить только существующие ID. Например "Так смотрю шяс ID 77, всё надо переходить на новый, опа ID 78 нету... хм ладно перейду на ID 79" - примерно так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами же стопаете свой таймер по условию "иначе". Счетчик становится равен 78, в БД таких данных нет, if (readURK.Read()) == false и вы делаете стоп таймеру. Необходимо другое условие остановки, например вытащите при старте таймера максимальный АЙДИ в данной таблице и уже делайте проверку переменной timer с этим ID и только по етому условию стопайте таймер.

UPDATE:

```
    //при старте программы или когда вы там начинаете работу
    private List<int> idList = new List<int>(); //список, в котором будем хранить существующие ID 
    //Вытаскиваем из БД все ID
    //У вас уже есть данный код, в него только нужно добавить заполнение списка:
    //...
    //while(reader.Read())
    //{
    //......
    //   list.Add(reader.....);
    //......
    //}
    //Создаем таймер, сетим интервал, подписываем событие и тд
    //Запускаем таймер!

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer > idList.Count) //Условие выхода из цикла
        {
            //Сетим лейблы про окончание работ
            //Стопаем таймер
            return;
        }

        //Создаем и открываем соединение с БД, создаем тот же Ридер и все остальное....
        cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = " + idList[timer].ToString();

        MySqlDataReader readURK = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if ( readURK.Read())
            {
                //Сетим лейблы
                webBrowser1.Navigate(readURK["URL"].ToString());
                //Здесь же можно добавить логику по начислению кредитов и тд

                readURK.Close();
            }
            timer++;
        }
        finally
        {
            cnt.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, таким образом он будет останавливаться когда достигнет максимального ID, но по пути к максимальному, есть пропуски... как их обойти?

Comment: Они будут обходится автоматом так, как вы етого и хотите! Доходит до 78 елемента, его нет в БД и запрос ничего не вытащил. Срабатывает условие и оно равно ложь, как я писал выше. Вам надо убрать else, в котором вы стопаете таймер!!! Если уберете его, таймер НЕ остановится и будет работать далее... скоро он станет 79 и тд и тп... Условия выхода из цикла я уже описал.

Comment: Дак нет, у меня нету ID 1,2,3,4,5,6 и.т.д у меня сразу 77, и далее идет 79, а 78 нету... так вот мне надо сделать так чтобы 78 программа пропустила и сразу перешла к 79... механизм останова как только программа просмотрела максимальный ID я сделал, вот теперь только пропуски надо убрать.

Comment: Я вас понял - оно так и будет работать. Уберите только "иначе" из етого обработчика.

Comment: Если же вы хотите ограничить кол-во запросов к БД (сейчас для несуществующих ID все равно будут запросы к БД, хоть и данные не будут получены в ответ, так как таких там нет) и ускорить вашу программу, то есть другой способ: перед стартом таймера вытащите все ID из етой таблицы, определите их в какой-то удобный для вас контейнер и при каждом следующем срабатывании таймера берите просто следующий ID. Условие окончания работы - закончились айди в контейнере.

Comment: Дело в том что я не могу это написать программно.

"Я вас понял - оно так и будет работать. Уберите только "иначе" из етого обработчика."

Не работает, всё равно переходит на ID 78....

Comment: У нас какое то недопонимание получается... В вашей логике ID инкрементится каждый тик таймера и оно перейдет на 78, но вы при етом НИЧЕГО не делаете и тупо увеличиваете дальше счетчик (главное таймер не стопать), после он станет 79, 80, 81 и тд... Если прога смогла чото вытащить из бд с таким айди, то отработает ваш код, если нет, то просто идет дальше... Я не поиму, вам не подходит такой алгоритм?

Comment: Обьясняйте что конкретно не получается. Почему вам не подходит выдуманная нами ситуация? Почему вас огорчает, что айди становится 78 ?

Comment: http://i070.radikal.ru/1202/89/b0b48ba48f0a.jpg - вот посомтрите на базу, видите там один пропуск. Так вот мне нужно чтобы программа просмотрев ID 77, не пошла на ID 78, а перешла сразу на ID 79.

Почему огорчает? У меня программа типа "Авто-серфинг", там надо чтобы программа искала сайты именно по **существующим** ID

Comment: Я ето понял, я не поиму почему вас беспокоит ситуация, когда в программе ID станет 78? Ничего ведь не произойдет! После етого оно станет 79, как вы хотите и далее будет выполняться ваш код, как задумано?

Comment: Да но за то что пользователь просмотрит пустой ID программа ему выдаст кредиты... а это не нормально, когда за просмотр пустых страниц получаешь кредиты...

Comment: Воооооооооот, с етого ведь и надо было начинать :)

Comment: Теперь думаю я понял вашу логику... Я щас домои - буду через 1-2 часа, постараюсь запостить для вас полный листинг.

Comment: Хорошо, буду ждать с нетерпением :)

Comment: Он теперь вообще не переходи по ссылкам.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы ету часть, к-ю мы тут обсуждаем....